# Missing subject in the sentence

Tags: syntactic-analysis

Original sentence:

> Inform John that you have completed the tutorial and need your assigned mentor.

Is that grammatically correct, or it's misses an additional you:

> Inform John that you have completed the tutorial and **you** need your assigned mentor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called **conjunction reduction**, where the conjunction (and) allows the sentence fragments identified by the noun clause (that you) to be reduced.

The unreduced form is:

> Inform John **that you** (have completed the tutorial) and **that you** (need your assigned mentor).

and the reduced form is:

> Inform John **that you** (have completed the tutorial and need your assigned mentor).

Both of these are grammatically correct.

Comment: Conjunction reduction has been covered quite a few times already on ELU.